# AUTO_INCREMENT not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a strange problem where auto increment is not working as expected.

I have two tables Table 1 and Table 2.

All new entries go into Table 1.

After a few days, once Table 1 values go stale, they are moved into Table 2

Code that does that is roughly as shown here (which some parts hidden):

```
    $Transaction->Begin();

    /*
     * 1) Delete items from the original table (Table 1).
     *      
     */

    /*
     * 2) Delete rows that we are going to write if they already exist
     * in Table 2
     */

    /*
     * 3) Insert into Table 2
     *
    */

    $Transaction->Commit();
```

My problem is that after the archiving operation, when I try to insert new value into Table 1, I see that primary key which was set to auto increment is not working as expected. The new entries have the same key as the old value.

See the images attached

Table 1:

[image]

As shown here, the values 127 and 128 were newly inserted after archiving old entries to Table 2 (see the image below)

Table 2:

[image]

Table 2 already contains the values with key 127 and 128. It is guaranteed that value in Table 2 are always moved from Table 1 to Table 2 which is it's only source of insertion, which means the keys 127 and 128 MUST have been present in Table 1 at some point of time. I am at a loss here on how could ids 127 and 128 reappear in Table 1 when I insert new values.

Schema for Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`caseid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`caseid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Schema for Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
`caseid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`caseid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=129 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: you need to provide the schema of your tables, as well as a sample of the code you are using to insert, archive and delete. without that, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: I have added the schema. The code is simple running queries.

For deletion I simple use the DELETE FROM query.

For insertion, I use INSERT INTO query.

They are wrapped in a transaction because the archiving runs in a separate process.

Comment: This problem has been bothering me for a long time, but I never seen a real life evidence. So thank you for providing one. It seems you had your server restarted during these days. It's  weird indeed.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Looks like you are right. Thanks!